# Altium issue: Clearance design rule between via and pad of same net

Tags: altium

In Altium PCB designer I have setup the following default clearance design rules:

[image]

At the beginning I had this rule to be applied only to different nets but I later realized I need to have some rules for objects of the same net. Mainly to have a minimum distance between vias and pads of the same net.

So I then changed this rule to be applied for any net. Although this achieved what I wanted, it also created thousands of new violations that are mainly related to not having enough distance between a via and a track of the same net. See for example the images below. The first one shows all new violations that came after I changed the rule and the second shows one example of "false" violation:

[image]

[image]

However this is totally wrong, since in this case the track in intentionally connected to the via. However Altium thinks this violates the design rules.

Which of course makes somehow sense. I mean by following blindly the rules set, the tool should indeed raise these violations.

But then the question is how to achieve what I want without having all these "false" violations that appear where there is basically short-circuit / correct connection between track segments or track and pad or track and via.

Comment: When it comes to Altium rules, less is more. Trim down your rules as much as possible and simplify

Comment: OK, I would agree with you. But what do you mean specifically in this case? The only rule that applies is the default rule. The other with higher priority are not applicable, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show a special rule for vias and pads. It shows a rule for any copper to any other copper. If you want a special rule for vias and pads, make a rule restricted to vias and pads, and make that rule apply to same nets.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yeah, that is exactly what I need. But I don't know how to do it? Is that intuitive? Except you mean restrict the first object in the rule to, let's say via, and the second object, let's say pad. Well, now that I think of it that should work...

Comment: 1. Create new rule. 2. Change `where the first object matches` to "IsVia" 3. Change `where the second object matches` to "IsPad" 4. Adjust the clearance value as required. 5. Put the new rule priority just above the default rule.

Comment: @ThePhoton Well, thanks a lot! It works like I wanted. I will update the question with an answer. It never came to me that this rule could also be restricted to specific objects only. The big table below doesn't help at all in this direction.

Comment: @nickagian, feel free to post an answer (as opposed to editing the question). After 1 or 2 days you can also accept your own answer to prevent the question being promoted to the front page in search of more answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *"The Photon"* suggested, the situation can be solved by creating a special rule targeting specific only vias and pads or vias and vias of the same net. For example something like the rule shown below
[image]